# Given a website's root directory, find and return filepath to favicon

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I deal with a lot of development sites on my machine, and as such I'm building a landing page for my localhost root that will list out each site, which works great so far. I'd like to add a small thumbnail for each site's favicon, so how can I now search a site directory for the path to the favicon image? Each site has the following data in my script:

- URL (localhost)
- DocumentRoot

Most of the sites are in PHP, which poses an issue for things like get_file_contents() since the structure isn't always the same for where the ⟨link⟩ containing the favicon path is located.

Comment: Does `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` help you? Oh, and given mobile, Macs, etc, favicon is now [not quite as simple as it used to be](http://www.favicomatic.com/favicon-test).

Comment: No that doesn't quite get me anywhere. I already have the location of the document root, I need to find out where in the file system the icon lives. I know the 13 different sizes are ridiculous, once I can even get the parent path where the icons are, I should be able to parse a little more from there.

Comment: Is this a Javascript or PHP question?

Comment: I'd be open to using PHP or JS to do this, which is why both are tagged.